# Sympy: Calculating eigenvalues takes very long for (9,9) matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix `F`, which contains 9 variables, which are the cartesian coordinates of three vectors. The execution time for `F.eigenvals()` takes at least 15 minutes and I haven't been patient enough to wait even longer for the program to finish. My suspicion is that I'm doing something horribly wrong, which causes the very long calculation. Maybe it's the mixing of numpy and sympy objects, which causes the issue.

I have the three atoms of water with their respective masses from which I calculate a so-called mass matrix `M` using the function `Mmat`.

```py
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import u as u

def Mmat(*args):

    N = len(args)
    args = np.array([[arg*u]*3 for arg in args]).reshape(N*3)
    m = args**(-1/2)
    I = np.identity(3*N)

    return m*I

mO, mH1, mH2 = 16, 1, 1
M = Mmat(mH1,mH2,mO)
```

This mass matrix needs to be multiplied according to the formula `F = M*H*M` with a Hessian matrix `H` in order to yield the (9,9) matrix `F` from which the eigenvalues are extracted. The Hessian itself is defined by the partial derivatives of the potential `V` for the cartesian coordinates of the three atoms O,H1 and H2.

The calculation of the matrix `F` itself only takes a second, but applying the `.eigenvals()` method takes forever. Here's the function for calculating `H`:

```py
def dist(v1,v2):

    return ((v2-v1)**2).sum()**(-1/2)

def Hessian():

    kOH, kHH, dr1, dr2, dr3 = sy.symbols('kOH kHH dr1 dr2 dr3', real=True, positive=True)

    V = 1/2*kOH*(dr1)**2 +1/2*kOH*(dr2)**2 +1/2*kHH*(dr3)**2

    x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9 = sy.symbols('x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9', real=True)
    dOH10, dOH20, dH1H10 = sy.symbols('dOH10 dOH20 dH1H10', real=True, positive=True)

    vO = np.array([x1,x2,x3])
    vH1 = np.array([x4,x5,x6])
    vH2 = np.array([x7,x8,x9])

    r1 = dist(vO,vH1) - dOH10
    r2 = dist(vO,vH2) - dOH20
    r3 = dist(vH1,vH2) - dH1H10

    V = V.subs(dr1,r1).subs(dr2,r2).subs(dr3,r3)

    H = sy.hessian(V,[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9])

    return H

F = M*Hessian()*M
```

The real problem only occurs at the end:

```py
print(F.eigenvals())
```

Am I mixing object classes inappropreately? Is it the fact that there are large numbers in the mass matrix (6.022e26)? Is it normal for a matrix of this size to run so slowly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In principle, you should avoid *numerical* constructs in sympy computations such as `numpy` arrays, numerical constants, etc. All your matrices (and their elements) should be symbolic or non-numerical constants. However, most likely the resulting `9x9` matrix `F` is simply too complicated for sympy to provide a symbolic eigenanalysis. Maybe you can try first working on fewer dimensions, see if sympy is able to provide an answer and go from there.

Comment: Yeah I already found out that sympy apparently has to calculate 9! = 362880 terms when doing an eigenvalue calculation and that doing it with symbolic sympy objects slows that process down significantly. I'm currently trying to determine, if substituting all variables with numbers and only then doing the eigenvalue calculation will significantly speed up the process. In that case I will answer my own question and detail the caveat of only calculating eigenvals of big, dense square matrices once all variables have been substituted.

Comment: If you substitute all variables with (numerical) numbers and then attempt to find the eigenvalues of the resulting (numerical) matrix, the procedure will be significantly faster (instantaneous). Actually, you should stick to `numpy`/`scipy` in that case (no sympy routines or constructs) as `numpy` has optimized (fast) routines for purely numerical matrices. I am not sure if sympy is as fast in that case - it will certainly be faster than the symbolic matrix case, of course